# How to stop Apache from resetting the URL?

Tags: apache, reactjs, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm hosting my React app on hostgator which uses Apache. In order to enable refreshing of the page without getting 404 not found I need to create and edit an .htaccess file which looks like this right now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

What happens when I refresh the page on a subpage (/some-sub-page) is the index.html renders but the URL resets to root.com (without the /some-sub-page).

I want the index.html to render, but I also want to keep the url in order for React Router to kick in and serve the correct components.

I've gone through the Apache documentation as well as threads about .htaccess editing but none seems to cover the problem with the URL resetting.
How would one go about that?

Best regards.

Comment: Are you sure it's not React Router doing this redirect? The rewrite rules you've shown won't issue a redirect.

Comment: I agree with @ceejayoz, It could be react-router related.  Please post your router definitions like <Switch/> <Redirect/> <Route/> components.